# Android App doesn't work on all devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, apk

I'm trying to make a very simple android app using Android Studio, it should open with a splash screen, then open a WebView.
I made it, and it works perfectly on my phone (with android 4.4.2), but when I try to use it on other device, I only get a white screen. I tried to use on a phone with android 4.1.2 and 6.0, none of them worked.

Any ideas where could be the error?

Edit:
Here's the files
https://github.com/gethuliogripp/kitexp

Comment: With no code, no errors, and no debugging done by you?  No clue.  Step through it in a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: And give us the error log if you cannot figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, was creating a github and forgot to add. I dont get any errors, on my device it works perfectly, on other I get a white screen and after a few seconds the application closes.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem and I was getting no errors as well. You have to make sure the images you use in the app such as your web view and splashcreen actually fit the screen so the app doesn't run out of memory. So make sure your images in your drawable are almost the same size as your phone screen, for my background i made the image 3in by 5in and my app works on all devices now.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works... But I don't get why my shitty phone with 480x800 screen resolution was able to make it work with a 1242x2148 image and a phone with a 1440x2560 didn't... Now it comes a new problem... The app works, but the image is pretty ugly because of the low resolution...Do you know any workaround? Thanks for your help